# How to get real path in JSF in a SessionListener

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, servlet-listeners

my requirement is as follows:

**INFO:** icefaces upload component, uploads the files to relative folder and creates for each user a sub-directory in that folder with the sessionId.

**Requirement:** at the `sessionDestroyed` for each user, i want to get the real path, to delete current user folder.

i know how to get the real path with JSF as follows:

```
ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getContext();
        String deploymentDirectoryPath = ctx.getRealPath("/");
```

**Problem:** if you try to get the real path in `sessionDestroyed` you will get null pointer exception, so i was wondering if there's a way to initialize the variable `deploymentDirectoryPath` in the listener so i can use it in `sessionDestroyed` method, or maybe initialize the real path variable on application startup and use it here ?

please advise how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you haven't posted the actual code that relates to the problem, the following gives me the real path:

```
public class MySessListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpSession sess = se.getSession();
                sess.invalidate();
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        String realPath = se.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println("realPath: " + realPath);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
INFO: com.bhesh.demo.web.listener.MySessListener.sessionCreated(MySessListener.java:13)
INFO: com.bhesh.demo.web.listener.MySessListener.sessionDestroyed(MySessListener.java:26)
INFO: realPath: C:\Documents and Settings\Bhesh\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JsfMessageList\build\web\
```

Comment: i was trying the following code in sessionDestroy, maybe it's the problem ServletContext `ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getContext();
        String deploymentDirectoryPath = ctx.getRealPath("/");`

Comment: That's what I was actually guessing. Those are JSF related and IMO it's good to keep them within JSF.

Comment: There's not necessarily means of a `FacesContext` during session destroy because it can be executed without a HTTP request on a JSF resource. So `getCurrentInstance()` will return `null`. By the way, the `ExternalContext` has also a `getRealPath()` method. You should prefer using it. Having `javax.servlet` imports inside a JSF backing bean is a sign of a poor practice. Last but not last, you should really take into account that `getRealPath()` can return `null` when the container is configured to expand WAR in memory instead of disk. You shouldn't use it if you don't have 100% admin control.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the real path as follows:-

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
```

**EDIT:-**

As mentioned by BalusC in one of his answers, you should think twice before using `getRealPath("/")` because if one has not chose to expand the war file then, `getRealPath("/")` might return `null`.

Use `getExternalContext.getResourceAsStream` instead. as per, [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html), It is valid to call this method during application startup or shutdown.

Comment: Please first explain how this works inside a `HttpSessionListener`.

Answer (score -1):

Based on BalusC sound advice here and elsewhere one could write a general purpose function like this:

```
  String getPath(){

ExternalContext tmpEC;      

tmpEC = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();   
String realPath=tmpEC.getRealPath("/");
return realPath;    
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question, which is about getting the path during session teardown, when (as @BalusC explained in the comments to another answer) there *might not be a FacesContext*?

Comment: based my assumption on this: "By the way, the ExternalContext has also a getRealPath() method. You should prefer using it".  But being fairly new to JSF I suspect I misunderstood.

Comment: The method is fine. The point is **the whole context might not be available**. As in, your code will cause a NullPointerException in certain cases.